# MySQL Update query lag

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, stored-procedures, innodb

I am a newbie to MySQL (For Query too). In our project, we have used update queries in stored procedure which is taking too much time. 
Eg: `update sample set field=xxx where id=130;`
When I run this piece of command alone in MySQL workbench, it is approximately taking 1.62 seconds.

I don't know why it is taking this much of time.
I tried setting the following values in etc/mysql/my.cnf file, but it is taking the same 1.62 seconds

```
    1.innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 4
    2.innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10000M
    3.query_cache_size          = 268435456
    4.query_cache_type          = 1
    5.query_cache_limit         = 1048576
```

When I added the following commands, I got "job failed to start service" error

```
    1. innodb_log_file_size = 256M
    2. innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
    3. innodb_io_capacity = 2000
    4. innodb_read_io_threads = 8
    5. innodb_write_io_threads = 8
```

I am not sure, whether this is the way, its been designed to perform or it is lagging. Please help with answers. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is the `id` column an indexed column

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `where id=130` I mean this `id`

Comment: A field being "indexed" means that the field can be found with a principle similar to a dictonnary, instead of opening the book page by page, u go straight to the P part of the book to find the word "plus" for example. You can make an index on several fields, your database will use those indexs to run your queries faster. How to create an index : https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/creating-table-advance/create-index.php You want to make index for the fields in the where condition

Comment: No. Its not indexed. Just a userID column value

Comment: Can you run an EXPLAIN query for the above query as  ```EXPLAIN update sample set field=xxx where id=130;``` and share the result

Comment: @Surendar23 "Its not indexed. Just a userID column" -- that's why. The more rows your table has it will become slower. MySQL needs to read **the entire table**, not just the rows you want to update. If you want to use `id` as a filtering condition of your queries you should index it.

Comment: @Infamous MySQL version I am using is 5.5.6, So, I am unable to add EXPLAIN query

Comment: @Surendar23, that's ok, if we had that we can be sure that we are approaching the problem correctly. Since you haven't provided the DB schema its hard for us to give concrete instructions but, as others have pointed out adding an index for ID column should help

Comment: @The Impaler. Sorry for the mistake. UserId is a primary key, which I learned now gets indexed automatically. So, it is an indexed column by the way. My apologies.

Comment: If the column `id` is the primary key, then any query with the filtering condition `where id = 130` should be pretty much instantaneous, even if the table has billions of rows. That's because the engine only needs to seek a single row and update it. No table scan is necessary. If it's taking more than that, then please post the execution plan on the question; there may be something you are not telling us.